# Is there a wifi card mfg that *only* does a FOSS driver?

Tags: drivers

I want to buy a wifi card that works with Linux, and the *only* firmware + driver that is available is FOSS, and partially maintained by the mfg, and partly by the community.

Does this exist?

Comment: There's almost no wifi hardware thats competely ideologically FOSS pure I suspect. There's a lot of hardware that works perfectly well with linux out of the box - with support from the chipset makers, and with drivers inside the kernel. If you have some specific *practical* requirement, a question of this nature would work better asked as a generalised question "How do I find a wifi adaptor that supports feature X?". In addition - this is a hardware shopping question and explicitly off topic for SU, in my opinion.

Comment: Due to regulatory requirements, at least in the US, I don't think they can get their device FCC certified and then release the firmware as open source, because you could trivially circumvent the restrictions they place on tx power and frequency that prevent the device from broadcasting outside the unlicensed band. You'll find plenty of hardware where the drivers are FOSS, and even some hardware where the *only* (GNU/Linux) drivers are FOSS, but you won't find any open firmware, unless you start from a software-defined radio and build 802.11 manually on top of it, which would be hard.

Comment: Also, I don't know of any wifi cards that exist which *lack* drivers for Microsoft Windows, and Windows drivers are almost always proprietary, so if that is an additional implied criterion of your search, I think the answer to your question is just flat-out "no", even for drivers alone, ignoring the firmware issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers), it looks like some of the Atheros chipsets meet your requirements. (They have free drivers (ISC license, which is a BSD-style license) developed by the manufacturers, and don't require proprietary firmware). Possibly some of the Realtek drivers might qualify as well.

It looks like the most recent ones are those [supported](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k/devices) by the [ath9k project](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k).

Comment: I believe the Realtek ones still require proprietary firmware, but there are two FOSS *driver* implementations for Realtek, one hacked by the FOSS community (with some Realtek employee assistance) and one that's older and provided by Realtek themselves. But the proprietary firmware pretty much counts them out, unless they have since released source code for their firmware.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article the rt2460, rt2560, rt2571, and rt2572 don't require firmware blobs. It may be wrong, of course... (edit) and I just noticed those are by Ralink and not Realtek. Still should meet the requirements, but the Atheros hardware is better, so...